# Create Random MSISDN 10 digit number

Tags: linux, shell

I want to create  MSISDN randomly like following
`905462108062`  via linux scripts. How I can make it possible?

Comment: invoke python/perl i think would be easiest way

Comment: Are there criteria for these numbers that you need to generate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of `date` and `RANDOM` to create a random 12-digit number:

```
#!/bin/bash

digits=12       # number of digits in final number
a=$(date +%s)
b=$((a*RANDOM))

while [ ${#b} -lt 12 ]; do
    b="${b}$RANDOM"
done

echo "${b:0:digits}"
```

**output example:**

```
$ bash msid12.sh
813376550037

$ for i in {1..5}; do bash msid12.sh; done
400816677371
258536046558
132352755855
335150875869
223675022781
```

Comment: should do `while [ ${#b} -lt ${digits} ]; do`

Answer (score 0):

(Your example data shows 12 digits in length)

```
for (( i=1; i<5;i++ )) ; do
    rand=$( printf "%06d%06d" ${RANDOM} ${RANDOM} )
    print $rand
done

017546028649
030586010983
015536009172
030430002707
```

To adjust size, you can change `%06d` (x 2) as needed.

I'm not sure of the max length of value produced by RANDOM, you may need to post-filter this output to trim to size.

IHTH